# cambiar tipo de dato de object a int64 en python usando pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy trabajando desde Python usando la librería pandas un archivo csv, en el siguiente link lo puede encontrar https://www.kaggle.com/ruchi798/movies-on-netflix-prime-video-hulu-and-disney
Y quiero cambiar el tipo de dato de la columna Rotten Tomatoes que es de tipo object a tipo float64, pues esta columna tiene números con porcentaje anexo imagen ilustrativa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para cambiar el tipo de dato he intentado dos códigos pero ninguno ha funcionado

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



Poyecto_EDA_DQ.Rotten Tomatoes=pd.to_numeric(Poyecto_EDA_DQ.Rotten Tomatoes, errors='coerce')
Poyecto_EDA_DQ.astype({'Rotten Tomatoes': 'float64'}).dtypes
```

Ninguno de estos dos códigos me funciona (el df se llama Poyecto_EDA_DQ)

Alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

Como primera recomendación NUNCA habras un archivo con extensión [csv] en MS Excel u otro interprete, por que puedes perder el formato original como en este caso.

Si te fijas, en realidad el campo 'Rotten Tomatoes' no es un valor numerico, si no un texto que representa la formula (Ej. 98% -> "98/100")

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo hice fue, separar los valores y aplicar la formula aparte, posterior a esto aplicar la división para llevarlo a un valor porcentual y con el formato requerido. Como lo muestro a continuación.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('MoviesOnStreamingPlatforms_updated.csv')

df['Rotten Tomatoes'] = df['Rotten Tomatoes'].str.split("/", n = 1, expand = True)
df['Rotten Tomatoes'] = df['Rotten Tomatoes'].fillna(0).astype(int) / 100
df['Rotten Tomatoes'].astype('float64')
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: Hola gracias por tu solución, pero no habrí el csv por aquí, es solo un pantallazo.

Comment: me sale el siguiente error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '87%'